# Optimize Superclass Method Depending on Subclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass, overriding

Can I provide a refined implementation (aka. override in OOP) of a method in a class instance, when the type is in another class, too? Or at least, if that other class is a subclass.

I have a class `C` with method `m`, a subclass `S` of `C` with method `s` and a type `T a` so there are instantiations

```
class C a where m :: [a] -> Bool
class C a => S a where s :: a -> a -> Bool
instance C a => C (T a) where m = ...
instance S a => S (T a) where s = ...
```

as usual.
Now it happens to be that when `T a` is in the subclass (which I cannot know as it depends on `a`), method `m` could be implemented much more efficient (quadratic vs. exponential time) using `s`.

I tried 'overriding' `m` in the implementation

```
instance S a => S (T a) where
    s = ...
    m = (all . uncurry) (=^=) . pairs -- override C.m
```

but the compiler errors basically because, `m` is not a public method of `S`. Well, it is not, but it's inherited in the OO sense.

For the specific purpose, the specialized version of `m` can be used for all instances; it's not a default to be overridden anywhere.

---

**Edit:** Because requested, the concrete code with a bit of explanation.

I have a class `Model` which has (among others) a method `con` that checks a list for consistency.

```
class Model a where
    con :: [a] -> Bool
```

Two models can form an arrow model.

```
data Arrow a b = [a] :->: b
lhs w = [ a | (u :->: _) <- w, a <- u ]
rhs w = [ b | (_ :->: b) <- w ]
```

For the specific instance `Model (Arrow a b)`, the general `con` implementation is very expensive (note `powerset` in the definition).

```
instance (Model a, Model b) => Model (Arrow a b) where
    con w = all (\w' -> con (lhs w') `implies` con (rhs w')) (powerset w)
```

There is a subclass `CoherentModel` of `Model` which has a method `(=^=)` that checks consistency for two objects. The condition for coherent models is that a list is consistent iff all pairs are.

```
class Model a => CoherentModel a where
    (=^=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    a =^= b = con [a, b]
```

The class `CoherentModel` is at this point more documentation than a feature.

So, given that a model is coherent, consistency is much more efficient to check.

```
instance (Model a, CoherentModel b) => CoherentModel (Arrow a b) where
    (u :->: a) =^= (v :->: b) = con (u ++ v) `implies` a =^= b
```

And in this case, `con` can be implemented using

```
con = (all . uncurry) (=^=) . pairs
  where
    pairs :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
    pairs [] = []
    pairs [_] = []
    pairs [x,y] = [(x,y)]
    pairs (x:xs) = map ((,) x) xs ++ pairs xs
```

but I find no way to specify this. It's not only for `Arrow`, it's relevant for all models with parameter. I chose `Arrow` because the improvement is significant.

Comment: Nitpicking: In the code included in the question, `S` is not a subclass of `C`. (By the way, though I realise you have posted an example abstracted from your concrete problem -- and so the following remark might be irrelevant -- looking at it I can't help but wonder if you actually need a subclass relationship. `s` and `m` feel a lot like `mappend` and `mconcat` from `Monoid` respectively; if your actual methods are in fact related in a similar way, you probably don't need subclassing.)

Comment: About `Monoid`: The signatures differ. Mine are predicates (ending with `Bool`), `Monoid`s are operations.

Comment: `override C.m` is a comment, right? Please don't use another language's syntax.

Comment: `m` is *not* inherited in any sense. As far as `S` is currently defined, you cannot assume that `T` *has* a `C` instance, and there is no reason to define `m` for an instance of `S`.

Comment: What you might want is `instance C (T a) where m = (all . uncurry) (=^=) . pairs` and `instance C (T a) => S (T a) where s = ...`.

Comment: If you really want `S` to be a subclass of `C`, the syntax is `class C a => S a where ...` This disallows defining an instance of `S` for a type unless it is also an instance of `C`. (See `Eq` and `Ord` as an example.)

Comment: @chepner, I fixed the code to match the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a good question.  One thing to remember is that whether a data type is an instance of a typeclass is *compile-time only* information -- i.e. we are always able to choose which instance to use using statically available information at the use site, and polymorphism comes from being able to choose an instance from the context. In general, if you ask "is `a` a member of typeclass `B`?", the only answers you can get are "yes" and "compile error".   (This second observation is changed a bit by `OverlappingInstances`, but it doesn't seem to help in your case)

So the answer to your immediate question is *no*.  You can't make a decision about a type's membership in a type class unless you are a method of that type class.  What we can do is add this decision as a method (using the [`constraints`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10) package)

```
import Data.Constraint

class Model a where
    con :: [a] -> Bool
    isCoherent :: Maybe (Dict (CoherentModel a))
    isCoherent = Nothing
```

Which you can define trivially for any type you have instantiated `CoherentModel` at:

```
instance Model Foo where
    con = ...
    isCoherent = Just Dict
```

Now you can implement your decision like this (w/ extensions `ScopedTypeVariables` and `TypeApplications`):

```
instance (Model a, Model b) => Model (Arrow a b) where
    con | Just Dict <- isCoherent @b = -- efficient implementation
        | otherwise                  = -- inefficient implementation
```

In the body of the first case we will have a local `CoherentModel b` in the context.  It's kind of cool.

Too bad we have a sort of [expression problem](http://wiki.c2.com/?ExpressionProblem) here where all the different implementations of `con` need to be collected up into one place.  Also too bad `isCoherent` needs to be implemented manually on each coherent `Model` instance, separate from where its `CoherentModel` instance is.

There is a lot to explore here but I have to go.  Good luck!

Comment: Do I have to define `isCoherent` to be anything? The compiler generates warnings for omitting the definition. In your example instance, you didn't.

Comment: @Bolpat, yes you do, I added an example of defining it.